# JS Ajax request produces error on localhost but not on web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Summary**

With identical code (in an asp.net core site), across different browsers, when browsing to a localhost IIS version of the page `XMLHttpRequest` detects some kind of error and calls its error event and sets status to zero despite having successfully read the data (network shows 200 OK) and stored it in `responseText`.

On a production/staging web server the code works perfectly normally every time.

Plaintext files appear to work OK locally as well for some reason (strictly speaking they are handled by an earlier middleware) but generated content (HTML and JSON) with normal headers produce the error.

My question is: Why does it produce this error now when it hasn't before?

Answer below...

**Full Original Post**

Until very recently (2-3 days ago) AJAX calls using jQuery's $.get() have been working fine on my development machine, and in the staging/production environments.

Since yesterday (when I noticed) AJAX calls now fail on the localhost version of the site and work fine on the production version.

I have tried in Firefox, Edge, and Opera - all have had the same result. I generated the most stripped down code I could and still can produce the same error result - which almost entirely rules out my code.

I checked the release notes for Firefox and Edge and couldn't find anything that appeared relevant to me.

The localhost is using a self-signed test certificate which has an exception in firefox. The staging site has a real 3rd party signed certificate.

The entirety of the page code is:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>@media print {#ghostery-purple-box {display:none !important}}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I run this javascript in the console window of each browser:

```
$.ajax({url:'/Test',error:function(a,b,c){alert(b)}, success:function(a){alert(a);}});
```

pardon the formatting, the single line was for simpler copy/pasting and testing.

the output in every configuration I can think of is the `alert(b)` part gets run and `b` equals "error".

The only differences in the two configurations is the URL:

`https://localhost:44300/Test`

vs

`https://[productionfqdn]:444/Test`

And the headers back from the webservers, locally it's IIS Express and remotely it's IIS - both backed by Kestrel as it's part of an ASP.NET Core site - though I've excluded any of that from being a possible part of the problem (I won't go into how much went into going back to previous version of code before I realised it was nothing to do with my code base).

IIS Express: (dev)

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
server: Kestrel
x-sourcefiles: [redacted]
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 23:05:06 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

IIS: (staging)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 23:04:47 GMT
```

The result of the calls to the localhost site are successful, in the devtools in FireFox I can see that the expected data has been returned, in this case the same data as was retrieved from /Test to start the test in the first place.

The result of the same calls on the staging site produces an alert with the html text as expceted.

I expect that these two environments produce the same result, namely, getting the html text back.

Any ideas? I am baffled!

**Edit 2019-03-28**
I tried, from the same page's context, to do the same with a vanilla XMLHttpRquest and got the following:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
undefined
x.open('GET', '/Test')
undefined
x.send(null)
undefined
x
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "",
response: "<h1>hi</h1>\r\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\"></script>"
```

Where one can clearly see the expected response from the web server in the object's response field. (line break for clarity)

The same, directly as an image from the browser devtools:

[image: Firefox javascript console]

**Edit 2 2019-03-28**

(aside, the network tab shows the data coming back fine)

So since the last edit seemed to indicate that jQuery is doing something silly, I decided to run the debugger and see what is happening in jQuery. In the current version (3.3.1) I broke at line 9300 which is after the request has been completed and after jQuery has assessed it. What I found was the done function appears to have values which differ between my local (dev) and remote (stg) web servers:

Local

[image: Local web server values]

Remote

[image: Remote web server values]

The primary crux is that the local version of jQuery is firing into `done()` with `status = 0` whereas the remote version is firing into `done()` with `status = 200` which makes sense.

In both versions the local `response` variable's state field is 'success'. On line 9247, jQuery is evaluating the `status` variable passed in to `done()` and because `0` is not passing, `isSuccess` is set to `false`.

However, the network shows:

[image]

I will continue to dig, but will watch out for any insightful responses :)

**Edit 3**

So `done()` is being called from line 9538:

```
callback = function( type ) {
                    return function() {
                        if ( callback ) {
                            callback = errorCallback = xhr.onload =
                                xhr.onerror = xhr.onabort = xhr.ontimeout =
                                    xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

                            if ( type === "abort" ) {
                                xhr.abort();
                            } else if ( type === "error" ) {

                                // Support: IE <=9 only
                                // On a manual native abort, IE9 throws
                                // errors on any property access that is not readyState
                                if ( typeof xhr.status !== "number" ) {
                                    complete( 0, "error" );
                                } else {
                                    complete(

                                        // File: protocol always yields status 0; see #8605, #14207
                                        xhr.status,
                                        xhr.statusText
                                    );
                                }
```

The line before `if ( typeof xhr.status !== "number" ) {` is checking `xhr.status` which is `0` and not an actual status code despite it definitely getting a 200 back. It explains where the message "error" is coming from! In `done()` it's checking that status code:

`isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;`

So where does that 0 come from?!

[image: jQuery handling XHR completion]

**Edit 4**

Ultimately the problem appears to be that `XMLHttpRequest` is giving me a status 0 from localhost and it didn't until a few days ago. Super frustrating:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open('GET', 'https://localhost:44300/Test'); x.send(null);
undefined
x
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", 
status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }

var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open('GET', 'https://127.0.0.1:44300/Test'); x.send(null);
undefined
x
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", 
status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

**Edit 5**

So again, trying to whittle it back to the minimum require to make an error. I rooted around in jquery for a bit and noted that the XHR was calling JQ's error callback (assigned to `xhr.onerror`) so I did the same vanilla:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest()
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 0, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }

x.onerror = function () {console.log('error happened')};
function onerror()

x.open('GET','/Test')
undefined
x.send(null)
undefined
error happened
x
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "<h1>hi</h1>\r\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js\"></script>" }
```

This caused the alert to show 'error happened' so I can say with some surety that it isn't jQuery but rather something weird that is causing an error locally.

**Edit 6**

Modified the above to be `x.onerror = function (e) {console.log('error happened'); console.log(e)};` to spew the error and got this:

```
error
  ​bubbles: false
  ​cancelBubble: false
  ​cancelable: false
  ​composed: false
  ​currentTarget: null
  ​defaultPrevented: false
  ​eventPhase: 0
  ​explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​  isTrusted: true
  ​lengthComputable: false
  ​loaded: 0
  ​originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
  ​returnValue: true
  ​srcElement: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
  ​target: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
  ​timeStamp: 594573
  ​total: 0
  type: "error"
```

Which doesn't shed a great deal of light.

**Edit 7**

Modifying my test page to be more comprehensive to allow me to do better testing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        x.onerror = function (e) { console.log('error happened'); console.log(e); $('#err').text(e); };
        x.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (x.readyState == 4) {
                $('#test').text(x.responseText);
            }
        };
        //x.open('GET', '/test.txt');
        x.open('GET', '/Search/Server?term=[redacted]');
        x.send(null);
    });
</script>
<h1>hi</h1>

<div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <pre id="test"></pre>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <pre id="err"></pre>
</div>
```

When I ask for `/test.txt` it works fine, `status = 200` no error

When I ask for `/Test` which is just this code I put above, `status = 0`, error produced (with no useful information as to why)

When I ask for `/Search/Server?term=[redacted]` which returns well-formed json, `status = 0`, error produced (with no useful information)

AJAX Headers (working)

```
HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified
content-type: text/plain
last-modified: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 06:20:18 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "1d4e52e505b3d27"
server: Kestrel
x-sourcefiles: [redacted]
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 06:47:09 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

AJAX Headers (not working)

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
server: Kestrel
x-sourcefiles: [redacted]
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 06:46:18 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

HTTP/2.0 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: Kestrel
x-sourcefiles: [redacted]
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 06:37:41 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

could it possible be the `charset` in the `content-type` header?!

It may be worth reiterating, all these calls with the *exact* same code works fine in production/staging - same browsers, same authentication (not that it is relevant after its happened), same relative URLs used, etc. Only difference is that prd/stg is IIS and has a real cert and local is IIS express and is using self signed with exception. That I can think of.

Comment: Could this be related to CORS? I've had the same symptom when I mess with variables related to CORS on my local machine, i.e. enabling or disabling the Chrome CORS extension.

Comment: I don't think so. The source is the same. When I do the same manual ajax request and specify a FQDN (say of the staging site from my local machine) then I get the appropriate CORS errors:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://[fqdn]:444/Test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]`

Otherwise it produced no error outputs in any of the 3 browsers I mentioned.

Comment: All those browser's include a _Network_ console where you can see the requests and responses. Are there any hints in there? Also, in your `error` handler, you should log the result of `c`

Comment: In my edit I added the value of `c`. `c` is an empty string. Also, I added the vanilla XHR, which shows the data comes back ok. About to add another edit with more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with a custom asp.net middleware which checks for a specific condition and then allows the pipeline to continue. I assume that whatever it did in development was causing the request to abort or have some quality that prevented it from working. Essentially the problem code was;

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Unimportant code here
    await _next(context);
    await Task.CompletedTask; // <<-- this line made it go wrong
}
```

replacing the problem line with 'return' fixed the issue.

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Unimportant code here
    await _next(context);
    return;
}
```

There is more work under the if statement, which is to be skipped if `IsDevelopment() == true` however I believe I didn't terminate this middleware properly in the first block here.

Why this returned a qualitatively different response to `XMLHttpRequest` is beyond me. I can't find anything that points towards a bad response.

The fact that the static files were coming OK via AJAX indicated that because it's an earlier middleware that it was probably my custom middleware that came later in the pipeline that was the problem.